# Downgrade SDK and build target android

Tags: android, xml, sdk, target

I'm almost done with my app, and, i admit i made a mistake. I set the min build target a 2.3.1 at the begining and now, i want to downgrade it to 2.1 at least. Everything looks fine except in xml files. i got this :

`error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'layout_width' with value 'match_parent').`

My question is quite simple : anyone know how can i fix that ? I don't think minSDK 7 refuses the "match parent", but maybe i'm wrong.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change match_parent to fill_parent.

Comment: Worked but i was wondering if that wasnt a problem from my workspace or something. :/
Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use fill_parent instead of match_parent.Hope this will work for you.match_parent is replaced by fill_parent for some higher version(Exact version from which it is deprecated I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

I tried in sdk 2.1 and match_parent is not working but in Google API 2.1 sdk match_parent is working so you can change the sdk version to Google API 2.1 and then test if it is working in real device if yes then match_parent will works fine otherwise change the match_parent to fill_parent 
hope it will help!!